# Cant crop exact image inside closed UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uibezierpath

I am using `JBCroppableView` to get the Bezier path of selected area.

// built in function to get path of selected area

```
UIBezierPath *path = [self getPath];
```

Only difference is that `JBCroppableView` masks the selected area and I am trying to crop the selected area.

Problem is that exact selected area is not being cropped. Some random outer area is also being cropped and the area cropped is nearly 1/4 of selected.
I am using the following code that in-takes bezier path and returns cropped image.

Code credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/originaluser2

```
-(UIImage*) cropImage:(UIImage*)image withPath:(UIBezierPath*)path { // where the UIBezierPath is defined in the UIKit coordinate system (0,0) is top left

    CGRect r = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path.CGPath); // the rect to draw our image in (minimum rect that the path occupies).

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, NO, image.scale); // begin image context, with transparency & the scale of the image.
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -r.origin.x, -r.origin.y); // translate context so that when we add the path, it starts at (0,0).

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath); // add path.
    CGContextClip(ctx); // clip any future drawing to the path region.

    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, image.size}]; // draw image

    UIImage* i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // get image from context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); // clean up and finish context

    return i; // return image
}
```

This is the selected area:

[image]

This is what I get after cropping:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the `UIBezierPath` that you're getting is defined in the `UIView`'s coordinate system - not the image coordinate system. What's wrong with the `JBCroppableView`'s `getCroppedImageWithTransparentBorders:` method?

Comment: @originaluser2: I want to get cropped image and then cropped image have to be set on image view. But right now i am getting cropped image along with white background that was supposed to be cropped